# Block an onChange event on a select when options are created by a v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

```html
<select v-on:change="WebserviceCall()">
<option v-for:="option in options">
</option>
</select>
```

Actually the on-change is triggered when the options are created in the v-for and i dont want this to happen, is there another semantic option or should i use a some kind of VueJSIsReady function in my javascript ?

Comment: If you add an initial "please select" style `<option>` with the value set to `null` (or some other default value), the change event will not trigger when the other options are changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a watcher to monitor for what to do when selectedValue is changed instead.

In HTML:

```
<select v-model="selectedOption">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:value="type.value">
    {{type.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
data: {
    selectedOption: '',
},
watch: {
    selectedOption(newVal) {
        // assuming all the available options are not ''
        if (newVal !== '') {
            // user has chosen an item
            this.webServiceCall()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should user vue watchers to watch selectedItem

```
  data:{
      selectedItem:'',
},
watch:{
   selectedItem(){
   this.callWebservice();
}
      }
```